# how to match a list of fixed length words separated by space or comma?

Tags: regex

The words' length could be 2 or 6-10 and could be separated by space or comma. The word only include alphabet, not case sensitive.

Here is the groups of words that should be matched:

```
RE,re,rereRE
```

Not matching groups:

```
RE,rere,rel
RE,RERE
```

Here is the pattern that I have tried

```
((([a-zA-Z]{2})|([a-zA-Z]{6,10}))(,|\s+)?)
```

But unfortunately this pattern can match string like this:  `RE,RERE`
Look like the word boundary has not been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match chars a-z either 2 or 6 - 10 times using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Then repeat that pattern 0+ times preceded by a comma or a space `[ ,]`.

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]{6,10}|[A-Za-z]{2})(?:[, ](?:[A-Za-z]{6,10}|[A-Za-z]{2}))*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z]{6,10}|[A-Za-z]{2})` Match chars a-z 6 -10 or 2 times
- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `[, ](?:[A-Za-z]{6,10}|[A-Za-z]{2})` Match comma or space and repeat previous pattern
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KGDDok/1)

If lookarounds are supported, you might also assert what is directly on the left and on the right is not a non whitespace character `\S`.

```
(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z]{6,10}|[A-Za-z]{2})(?:[ ,](?:[A-Za-z]{6,10}|[A-Za-z]{2}))*(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3PAmv/1)

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much. I just tried and your pattern is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}(,|\s)|[a-zA-Z]{6,10}|(,|\s))
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match your first case, but neither of your two other cases:

`^((([a-zA-Z]{2})|([a-zA-Z]{6,10}))(,|[ ]+|$))+$`

I'm making the assumption here that each line should be a single match.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/vdI0IA/3/) it is in action.

Answer (score 0):

This one will get only the words who have 2 letter, or between 6 and 10

```
\b,?([a-zA-Z]{6,10}|[a-zA-Z]{2}),?\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
^(?!.*\b[a-z]{4}\b)(?:(?:[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{6,10})(?:,|[ ]+)?)+$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/jO5mMZ/2/)